# Proguard Invalid class reference: android/support/v4/app/Fragment

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, proguard, android-proguard

I've been trying to get Proguard to work in this libgdx app of mine for hours, and I can't get past this error when I try running it:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':android:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.ClassLookupException: Invalid class
>   reference: android/support/v4/app/Fragment

I've tried adding a ton of different rules to `proguard-rules.pro`, nothing seems to work. Here are some of the rules I've tried:

- `dontwarn android.support.**`
- `keep class android.support.v4.* { *; }`
- `keep public class * extends android.support.v4.`
- `keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment`
- `dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb`
- `keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }`
- `optimizationpasses 5`
- `keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`
- `keep class android.support.** { *; }`

Here's what my `buildTypes` look like in my Android `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

### Edit

This is definitely a LibGDX problem, I tried it with a blank LibGDX project and I get the exact same error.